# How do I send with brotli encoding of a Google Cloud Function HTTP response

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do i set content-encoding in response? If i set `res.header("content-encoding", 'br')` and send brotli version

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  res.header("content-encoding", 'br')
  let message = Buffer.from('Hello World!');
  res.write(brotli.compress(message));
  res.end();
};
```

google function overwritten `content-encoding` and get the value `content-encoding: gzip`

Comment: You have to perform the compression yourself.  Just setting the header won't automatically compress it the way you want.

Comment: Yea i compressed it with brottli but google function overwrite content-encoding and browser does not parse right

Comment: @Tom910 where you able to resolve this issue? Doing compression yourself and correctly sending the data? If so, could you please share your answer! Thanks

Comment: @pagep I didn't find solution and didn't use google function in that case

Answer (score 4):

To utilize brotli compression with GCP Cloud Functions you have to use onRequest
type of functions which exposes the express response where you can change the response headers.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as zlib from "zlib";

const runTest = functions
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    // Allowing CORS on my function
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")


    zlib.brotliCompress(JSON.stringify({something: "this is test"}), ((error, result) => {
      if(error){
        console.error("Error", error)
        response.status(500).end()
      }

      response.set("content-encoding", "br")
      response.send(result);
    }))
}

export { runTest };
```

I went from 50kB as gzip to 20kB with brotli.

However there is additional issue you have to consider. Brotli compression is much more demanding for CPU to compress. There are different compression options, you might consider changing them based on the size of your data. I didn't play with them yet. Also we could probably stream the data? Do some tweaks with the express framework.

EDIT:
This is my stream implementation with tweaked parameters for my use-case.
I am at the same response time values as with gzip with the same CF performance and 40% decrease in the transferred size. (FYI: I had some really slow response times before I tweaked the parameters, I think the BROTLI_MODE_TEXT helped a lot!)

```js
import * as stream from "stream";

const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(inputData);

const inputStream = new stream.Readable(); // Create the stream
inputStream.push(stringifiedData); // Push the data
inputStream.push(null); // End the stream data

const passTrough = new stream.PassThrough()

const brotli = zlib.createBrotliCompress(  {
  chunkSize: 32 * 1024,
  params: {
    [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_MODE]: zlib.constants.BROTLI_MODE_TEXT,
    [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 4,
    [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_SIZE_HINT]: stringifiedData.length
  }});

inputStream.pipe(brotli).pipe(passTrough)

passTrough.on('data', (data) => {
  response.write(data);
})

passTrough.on('end', () => {
  response.end();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible because according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#http_frameworks) Google Cloud functions for NodeJS use Express 4 To handle HTTP, and per this [Express GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/71) Brotli is not supported

Comment: In my case i have disable express compression

Comment: Compression plugin in same case work fine https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/master/index.js#L165

Comment: Are you using the NodeJS standard run-time? How did you disabled the express compression?